# How to get members of a Windows (security) group?

Tags: windows, security, winapi

### Short Version

What is the Windows function to list all members of a Windows (security) group?

### Long Version

The gotcha is that we can't just skip directly to Active Directory, because it's entirely *possible* that the group is not an group in Active Directory, because not all groups will be in Active Directory, because some groups can be local to the machine, and some machines may not even be joined to a domain.

For example:

- `STACKOVERFLOW\ITOps`: a group in the <kbd>STACKOVERFLOW</kbd> domain
- `ITOps@stackoverflow.com`: a group in the <kbd>stackoverflow.com</kbd> domain
- `HOTH\docker-users`: a group on the local machine

Reminder that <kbd>STACKOVERFLOW</kbd> and <kbd>stackoverflow.com</kbd> happen to be two names for the same domain.

This will then remind you that <kbd>STACKOVERFLOW\ITOps</kbd> and <kbd>ITOps@stackoverflow.com</kbd> are two names for the same group.

- The first is the Windows name.
- The second is the matching name in Active Directory.

You can convince yourself of this by calling [**LookupAccountSid**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupaccountsida), which returns:

- **Name**: *"ITOps"*
- **Domain**: *"STACKOVERFLOW"*

And you can see it in when running `whoami /groups`:

```
| Group Name                                           | Type             | SID                                            |
|------------------------------------------------------|------------------|------------------------------------------------| 
| HOTH\PoleDancers                                     | Alias            | S-1-5-21-508675309-3072756349-3142140079-1006  |
| HOTH\docker-users                                    | Alias            | S-1-5-21-508675309-3072756349-3142140079-1014  |
| STACKOVERFLOW\Stackoverflow Users                    | Group            | S-1-5-21-1701128619-854245398-2146844275-1132  |
| STACKOVERFLOW\Project Managers                       | Group            | S-1-5-21-1701128619-854245398-2146844275-3626  |
| STACKOVERFLOW\MSFT Developers                        | Group            | S-1-5-21-1701128619-854245398-2146844275-3608  |
| STACKOVERFLOW\Stackoverflow Admins                   | Group            | S-1-5-21-1701128619-854245398-2146844275-1136  |
| STACKOVERFLOW\Audit                                  | Group            | S-1-5-21-1701128619-854245398-2146844275-3627  |
| STACKOVERFLOW\Domain Admins                          | Group            | S-1-5-21-1701128619-854245398-2146844275-512   |
| STACKOVERFLOW\Enterprise Admins                      | Group            | S-1-5-21-1701128619-854245398-2146844275-519   |
| STACKOVERFLOW\DnsAdmins                              | Alias            | S-1-5-21-1701128619-854245398-2146844275-1107  |
| STACKOVERFLOW\Denied RODC Password Replication Group | Alias            | S-1-5-21-1701128619-854245398-2146844275-572   |
| STACKOVERFLOW\DHCP Administrators                    | Alias            | S-1-5-21-1701128619-854245398-2146844275-1004  |
| BUILTIN\Performance Log Users                        | Alias            | S-1-5-32-559                                   |
| BUILTIN\Performance Monitor Users                    | Alias            | S-1-5-32-558                                   |
| BUILTIN\Users                                        | Alias            | S-1-5-32-545                                   |
| BUILTIN\Administrators                               | Alias            | S-1-5-32-544                                   |
| NT AUTHORITY\REMOTE INTERACTIVE LOGON                | Well-known group | S-1-5-14                                       |
| NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE                             | Well-known group | S-1-5-4                                        |
| NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users                     | Well-known group | S-1-5-11                                       |
| NT AUTHORITY\This Organization                       | Well-known group | S-1-5-15                                       |
| Everyone                                             | Well-known group | S-1-1-0                                        |
| LOCAL                                                | Well-known group | S-1-2-0                                        |
| Authentication authority asserted identity           | Well-known group | S-1-18-1                                       |
| Mandatory Label\Medium Mandatory Level               | Label            | S-1-16-8192                                    |
```

So: given a group, i need the members.

- the group could be local
- the group could be on the domain
- i don't **know** if the group is local or part of a domain
- i don't **care** if the group is local or part of a domain

I need Windows to tell me the members.

And remember:

- a local group
- can contain local users
- can contain local groups
- can contain domain users
- can contain domain groups

So, by definition, trying to query Active Directory is simply wrong.

### Short version

Given a **group security identifier (SID)** how do i get the members of that group?

I know it's possible, because Windows does it right there in `netplwiz`:

[image]

Showing a mix of local and domain users at the same time.

## Bonus Reading

- [Active Directory: Get all group members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137022/active-directory-get-all-group-members)
- [How to get members in a local windows group using LDAP and c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320488/how-to-get-members-in-a-local-windows-group-using-ldap-and-c)
- [Get members of Windows Group with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358331/get-members-of-windows-group-with-python)
- [Get windows group members along with their domain names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454019/get-windows-group-members-along-with-their-domain-names)
- [How to determine membership of user in well-known-groups as Everyone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494866/how-to-determine-membership-of-user-in-well-known-groups-as-everyone)

Comment: As a reminder: Stack overflow is a programming website. As a result this is a programming question. And I'm looking for a programming answer.

Comment: You want `NetGroupGetUsers()` et al.

Comment: @bad_coder This is Stackoverflow; I was asking a programming question.

Comment: @Luke [Is there any syntax of `NetGroupGetUsers()` that works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72189969/netgroupgetusers-returns-nerr-groupnotfound)

Comment: You can use [NetQueryDisplayInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netquerydisplayinformation#examples) to Return group account information. Perhaps you need [NetLocalGroupGetMembers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netlocalgroupgetmembers).

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT **NetLocalGroupGetMembers** works great for groups that are local, but fails on groups that are from the domain. So that's no good.

Comment: Or *NetQueryDisplayInformation* can return group account information which can be passed to *NetGroupGetUsers*.